# Serialize stochastic hashing function to be language-agnostic

Tags: python, c++, serialization, random

I'm using the hashing function from [here](https://github.com/YannDubs/Hash-Embeddings/blob/master/hashembed/embedding.py) as part of a machine learning model. I need to use the trained model in C++, and thus I need the hashing function to be independent of the language (in this case Python/C++). How do I serialize a stochastic hashing function such that I can recreate the exact same hashing with same stochasticity in another language (C++)?

Comment: It would probably be easier to transfer a simpler hashing function between languages.  Assuming that you do not need a cryptographic hash, then I like the [FNV hash](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/) which has the additional advantage of coming in a variety of sizes, so you have more flexibility.  Note the difference between FNV1 and FNV1a, be sure to specify what variant you want to use.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! It does seem, however, based on the repo README that the hash function needs to a [universal hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing).